# How to handle case-sensitive SPARQL for Wikidata Query Service

Tags: sparql, case-sensitive

Im trying to perform searchs on wikidata, but my query its a little weird. Some searchs are case-sensitive

EG: using "maradona" match perfectly but "cristiano ronaldo" don't. "Cristiano Ronaldo" match OK.

[wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel (SAMPLE(?RIP) AS ?RIP) (SAMPLE(?image) AS ?image) WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5;
    ?label "cristiano ronaldo"@en.
  ?article schema:about ?item;
    schema:inLanguage "en".
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P570 ?RIP. }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P18 ?image. }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
  
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
```

I expect to be able to search all with lowercase (or other way to handle it better)

Comment: efficient text search on Wikidata is one of the most frequent questions on StackOverflow ...

Comment: `SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?type ?typeLabel WHERE {   SERVICE wikibase:mwapi {       bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" .       bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" .       bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "christiano ronaldo" .       bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en" .       ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item .       ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true .   }   ?item (wdt:P279|wdt:P31) ?type   SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }  } ORDER BY ASC(?num) LIMIT 10`

Comment: the rest is up to you, just combine both queries and hopefully this is sufficient for your task